Can the minimisation operation be seen from a programming language perspective?
If $f$ is a total function $\mathbb N^k\to\mathbb N$, and $g$ is a total function $\mathbb N^{k+2}\to\mathbb N$, then we say that $h:\mathbb N^{k+1}\to\mathbb N$ is definable by primitive recursion from $f$ and $g$ if for all $x_1,\dots,x_k\in\mathbb N$ and $y\in\mathbb N$,
\begin{align}
h(x_1,\dots,x_k,0)&=f(x_1,\dots,x_k), \\
h(x_1,\dots,x_k,y')&=g(x_1,\dots,x_k,y,h(x_1,\dots,x_k,y)),
\end{align}
where $y'$ denotes the successor of $y$.
Primitive recursion can be seen as corresponding to a "for loop" in a programming language – the following pseudocode computes $h(x_1,\dots,x_k,y)$:
INPUT x1,...xk,y
value = f(x1,...,xk)
for i=0 to y:
    value = g(x1,...,xk,i,value)
RETURN value

I find such an explanation quite valuable, since it reinforces the idea that general recursive functions are ones that can be "computed" in a reasonable sense. Is there a similar way in which the minimisation operation can be understood? More specifically, does minimisation correspond to some kind of "loop" found in programming languages?

For reference, the minimisation operation can be defined as follows:
If $f:\mathbb N^{k+1}\rightharpoonup \mathbb N$ is a partial function, then the minimisation $m:\mathbb N^k\rightharpoonup\mathbb N$ of $f$ is given by the following rule: if $f(x_1,\dots,x_k,t)$ is defined and $\neq0$ for all $t<y$, and $f(x_1,\dots,x_k,y)=0$, then $m(x_1,\dots,x_k):=y$; if there is no such $y$, then $m(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ is undefined.


Is there a similar way in which the minimisation operation can be understood? More specifically, does minimisation correspond to some kind of "loop" found in programming languages?

Yes, minimisation corresponds to possibly non-terminating loops. It increments t and searches for the first 0 value. When the function is undefined it means that it is looping forever.
INPUT x1,...xk
t = 1
value = f(x1,...,xk,t)
while value != 0:
     t = t + 1
     value = f(x1,...,xk,t)
RETURN t

Note that when f is undefined, it also would not terminate.

Might want to clarify, op gives a definition for the bounded minimization operator, while this answer gives an example of the unbounded minimization operator (aka μ operator)

@BurnsBA correct me if I’m wrong, but the op gives the definition for unbounded minimization (its arity is one less than f). Bounded minimization would be a total function

op definition says "...for all $t<y$...". This answer has no limit on $t$. See perhaps https://planetmath.org/boundedminimization . This question might be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1276185/114910

@BurnsBA I think you might be misunderstanding, $y$ is the result of the minimization in ops definition, not $t$.  There's no upper bound on y.

Correct, there is no bound on $y$`, but there is a bound on $t$, which makes op's definition the bounded minimization operator while this answer is the unbounded minimization operator.

@BurnsBA no, the bound is in the antecedent of a conditional, it reads that the result of the minimization is equal to y if for all t < y, …. The bound of t is y, but y is the result, not a parameter, so the search is not bounded. There is no ultimate bound on y. See definition here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_recursive_function where the i is OP’s t.
